# Joining streaming data on table data and update the table as the stream receives , is it possible?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-streaming, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1 , spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8.
I have scenario , where I need join streaming data with C*/Cassandra table data.

If record/join found I need to copy the existing C* table record to another table_bkp and update the actual C* table record with latest data.

As the streaming data come in I need to perform this.
Is this can be done using spark-sql steaming ?
If so , how to do it ? any caveats to take care ?

For each batch how to get C* table data freshly ?

> **What is wrong I am doing here**

I have two tables as below "master_table" & "backup_table"

```
table kspace.master_table(
    statement_id int,
    statement_flag text,
    statement_date date,
    x_val double,
    y_val double,
    z_val double,
    PRIMARY KEY (( statement_id ), statement_date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( statement_date DESC );

table kspace.backup_table(
    statement_id int,
    statement_flag text,
    statement_date date,
    x_val double,
    y_val double,
    z_val double,
    backup_timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((statement_id ), statement_date, backup_timestamp )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( statement_date DESC,   backup_timestamp DESC);


Each streaming record would have "statement_flag" which might be "I" or "U".
If record with "I" comes we directly insert into "master_table".
If record with "U" comes , need to check if there is any record for given ( statement_id ), statement_date in "master_table".
     If there is record in "master_table" copy that one to "backup_table" with current timestamp i.e. backup_timestamp
     Update the record in "master_table" with latest record.
```

To achieve the above I am doing PoC/Code  like below

```
Dataset<Row> baseDs = //streaming data from topic
Dataset<Row> i_records = baseDs.filter(col("statement_flag").equalTo("I"));
Dataset<Row> u_records = baseDs.filter(col("statement_flag").equalTo("U"));

String keyspace="kspace";
String master_table = "master_table";
String backup_table = "backup_table";


Dataset<Row> cassandraMasterTableDs = getCassandraTableData(sparkSession, keyspace , master_table);

writeDfToCassandra( baseDs.toDF(), keyspace, master_table);


u_records.createOrReplaceTempView("u_records");
cassandraMasterTableDs.createOrReplaceTempView("persisted_records");

Dataset<Row> joinUpdatedRecordsDs =  sparkSession.sql(
            " select p.statement_id, p.statement_flag, p.statement_date,"
            + "p.x_val,p.y_val,p.z_val "
            + " from persisted_records as p "
            + "join u_records as u "
            + "on p.statement_id = u.statement_id  and p.statement_date = u.statement_date");

    

Dataset<Row> updated_records =   joinUpdatedRecordsDs
                            .withColumn("backup_timestamp",current_timestamp());

updated_records.show(); //Showing correct results 


writeDfToCassandra( updated_records.toDF(), keyspace, backup_table);  // But here/backup_table copying the latest "master_table" records
```

> **Sample data**

**For first record with "I" flag**

master_table

[image]

backup_table

[image]

**For second record with "U" flag , i.e. same as earlier except "y_val" column data**

master_table

[image]

backup_table

Expected

[image]

But actual table data is

[image]

**Question:**

Till show the dataframe(updated_records) showing correct data.
But when I insert same dataframe(updated_records) into table , C* backup_table data shows exactly same as latest record of master_table , but which suppose to have earlier record of master_table.

```
  updated_records.show(); //Showing correct results 
    
    
    writeDfToCassandra( updated_records.toDF(), keyspace, backup_table);  // But here/backup_table copying the latest "master_table" records
```

So what am I doing wrong in above program code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to to do this with various levels of performance depending on how much data you need to check.

For example, if you are only looking up data by partition key the most efficient thing to do is to use joinWithCassandraTable on the Dstream. For every batch this will extract records matching the incoming partition keys. In structured streaming this would happen automatically with the correctly written SQL join and DSE. If DSE was not in use it would fully scan the table with each batch.

If instead you require the whole table for each batch, joining the DStream batch with a CassandraRDD will cause the RDD to be re-read completely on every batch. This is much more expensive if the entire table is not being re-written.

If you are only updating records without checking their previous values, it is sufficient to just write the incoming data directly to the C* table. C* uses upserts and last write win behaviors, and will just overwrite the previous values if they existed.

Comment: Probably a clock issue. Since Cassandra uses lww, if your clock on the executor is behind the data already written it won't update it. Also possible that your write df function is broken

Comment: Fix you clock with ntp, make sure the old records weren't inserted with an old timestamp. If your other function is broken I couldn't tell you how without seeing the code.